# Phonegap background image for iOS not working

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I'm working with Phonegap to develop an application for the iPhone.

I have the application design from our designer, and am trying to set the background for the index.html page. No matter what code I try, I cannot get it to display and I always end up with a white background.

I tried this but didn't work

```
<body style="background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100%;" >
```

I also tried creating a class in the end of the JQuery CSS file, and applying it to the main div or body of the page, that didn't work too

I even tried to override the whole body CSS, that didn't work either

```
body         {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, if you display the image normally on the page, it it exists and renders, correct?

Comment: You might post a public sample on your server, or at jsfiddle or codepen, because your code appears to be syntactically correct, so other than being able to dig into an example there's not much to tell you from the code above.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the path is correct i.e. images folder is at same path as HTML page, or at CSS level if declared in CSS. If not that try putting `images/bg.jpg` in single quotes, so:

```
<body style="background: url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: 100%;" >
```